# How to add customize dropdown for selecting country in the header in opencart

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

I am making a ecommerce website http://www.krushti.com

I want to add a dropdown for country in my header part ,so that a particular user can select the country and the currency should also change as well. 
Do we have any option in the admin panel or do we have to code it manually. But i think coding part will be more tedious and also not recommended mostly in opencart.

Please help me in customization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to code it, or purchase it, opencart doesn't have an admin panel for that

Answer (score 0):

use [Drop Down Modification Plugin](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5947),it is free and it will help to display currencies in drop down list. For the title (Country Name + Currency) go to

```
admin>system>localization>currencies
```

Here you can add or modify according to your need.